# curl with `-k` and without `-k`

Tags: ssl, curl, nginx, haproxy, insecure-connection

When I am opening a url using `curl` **without** `-k`, my request is passing and I am able to see the expected result.

```
$ curl -vvv https://MYHOSTNAME/wex/archive.info -A SUKU$RANDOM
*   Trying 10.38.202.192...
* Connected to MYHOSTNAME (10.38.202.192) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.MYCNAME
* Server certificate: ProdIssuedCA1
* Server certificate: InternalRootCA
> GET /wex/archive.info HTTP/1.1
> Host: MYHOSTNAME
> User-Agent: SUKU19816
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.2
< Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2017 01:08:40 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 19
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1XXXXXXXX3E58093E816FE62D81; Path=/wex/; HttpOnly
< X-WebProxy-Id: 220ffb81872a
< 




status=Running
* Connection #0 to host MYHOSTNAME left intact
```

But when I am opening same url **with** `-k` its failing. To me its not making any sense since in my understanding the purpose of `-k` is only to skip certificate verification

```
$ curl -vvv https://MYHOSTNAME/wex/archive.info -A SUKU$RANDOM -k
*   Trying 10.38.202.192...
* Connected to MYHOSTNAME (10.38.202.192) port 443 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

Request flow:

1. SSL termination is happening on HAPROXY machine
2. HAPROXY will forward request to nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For troubleshooting this kind of problem, the [`--resolve` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) can be useful:

```
curl -k -I --resolve www.example.com:80:192.0.2.1 https://www.example.com/
```

> Provide a custom address for a specific host and port pair. Using
>   this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified address and
>   prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to be used. Consider
>   it a sort of /etc/hosts alternative provided on the command line. The
>   port number should be the number used for the specific protocol the
>   host will be used for. It means you need several entries if you want
>   to provide address for the same host but different ports.

Especially if the site you’re trying to fetch from uses SNI: In that case you can use the `--resolve` option to specify the server name that gets used in the TLS client hello.

One troubleshooting step to try: update `curl` or [compile it yourself from the sources](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) and retry. For one thing, some `curl` versions (e.g., MacOS) supposedly don’t send SNI for `-k`/`--insecure`.

If that’s the issue you’ve hit and you can’t replace `curl`, [there’s a workaround you can use](https://coolaj86.com/articles/create-your-own-certificate-authority-for-testing/) that essentially involves creating your own CA and private keys and CSRs, and tweaks to your haproxy.

After setting it up, then in place of specifying `-k`/`--insecure`, you use `--cacert` or `--capath`:

```
curl https://example.com/api/endpoint --cacert certs/servers/example.com/chain.pem
curl https://example.com/api/endpoint --capath certs/ca
```

If the issue you’ve hit is due to SNI, you may also troubleshoot it with a site like https://sni.velox.ch/:

```
curl --insecure https://sni.velox.ch/
```

Otherwise, if it’s not SNI, then I recall seeing somewhere that `-k`/`--insecure` may not work as expected with some proxy configurations. So if you are going through some kind of proxy from the client side and you could somehow test directly without the proxy, that might be worth exploring.

Comment: Thanks sideshowbarker. Yes,it was due to SNI bug in curl which I was using. I found about  this mac curl bug from this http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?10,1241932